# Proper cellpadding for all longtables wanted

Tags: longtable

I want to add cellpadding to my longtables. This works by writing

```
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{longtable}[H]{|m{0.1\linewidth}m{0.9\linewidth}|}\hline
  Content
\end{longtable}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
```

I figured this out just some time ago. Now I have a lot of longtables that are not surrounded by

```
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
```

I originally expected that doing a one-time `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}` at the beginning of the document is enough. But this is not the case. It is reset throughout the document.

How would you surround all existing longtables the most easiest way? Some Bash magic here?

Comment: What's `[H]` supposed to do? It does nothing at all. Moreover, your tables will be *all* consist of overfull lines, because you're forgetting to remove the intercolumn spaces and the rule widths.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the value of \arraystretch is often not a good solution, as the contents of a cell is no more vertically centred in the cell.

That said, you can add these lines in your preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox} 
\AtBeginEnvironment{longtable}{\renewcommand\arraystretch{2}}
```

*Another solution:*

Add:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox, makecell} 
\setcellgapes{5pt} % vertical padding added at the top and bottom of cells
\AtBeginEnvironment{longtable}{\makegapedcells}
```

Comment: Just wanted to mention that this answer also works when putting TextFields into Tables.